# How can we get the child scope value in function and toggle it (Angular Js)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Can we change the dom level child scope value using javascript function?

```
 <article data-ng-init="show=true" data-ng-repeat="a in obj track by $index">
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="submit_btn" data-ng-bind="a.name" data-ng-click="ajaxCall(a,$event,show);"></div>
    </div>
    <ahref ="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="show=true></a>
    </article>
```

####Controller

```
$scope.ajaxCall = function (obj,event,show){

//after ajax success togggle show

show = !show; //nothing is happening
};
```

Comment: Try making that $scope.show.

Comment: you need to put that in `$scope`

Comment: $scope.show = !show;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now  `show` property shared by all article.So, `whatever you do changes in it, will affect to all`.

You can define html as follows.

Assign show property to each `a` object.

So,it will affect only respected article.

```
<article data-ng-init="a.show=true" data-ng-repeat="a in obj track by $index">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="submit_btn" data-ng-bind="a.name" data-ng-click="ajaxCall(a,$event,a.show);"></div>
    </div>
    <ahref="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="sa.how=true">
        </a>
</article>
```

And call `ajaxCall` method with `a.show`

Answer (score 3):

I think you did just forgot a `$scope`...:

```
$scope.ajaxCall = function(obj, event, show) {
  // on ajax call success, toggle $scope.show
  $scope.show = !show; // something should happen... :-)
};
```

Comment: data-ng-repeat is there new child instances

Comment: Say we have 5 same ajaxcall on the page which $scope.show will be changed via this method?

Comment: You could use an *Array* of booleans instead of a single boolean, and use `$index` for the array index...

Answer (score 1):

This could help

```
$scope.show = [];
$scope.ajaxCall = function(obj, event, index) {
  // after ajax success toggles show
  $scope.show[index] = !$scope.show[index];
};




<div class="submit_btn" data-ng-bind="a.name"
     data-ng-click="ajaxCall(a,$event,$index);"></div>
```